# TeamsUserCredential is not supported in Node

Tags: microsoft-teams, react-testing-library

I'm working on a React application that's embedded in MS Teams and I'm trying to render a component with React Testing Library for automated testing. I'm getting error:
"TeamsUserCredential is not supported in Node"

I cannot find information on this anywhere so decided to post it here. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm handling it with regular mocking now. Sorry to waste your time.